# How to efficiently calculate cotangents from vectors

Tags: c++, geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to implement a function to compute the cotangents of vectors (the mathematical ones) via the standard formula:

> cot(**a**, **b**) = (**a** * **b**) / |**a** x **b**|, where **a** and **b** are vectors

A colleague told me that calculating `1/|a x b|` is not the best thing to give a computer to calculate. Another alternative coming to my head is first calculating the angle and than using cotan functions for radians angles.

What would be the method of choice here? (Is there maybe another one, other than the mentioned ones)

Comment: If your formula means: (xa.ya+xb.yb)/(xa.yb-xb.ya), it seams fine for me as long as xa.yb is not equal to xb.ya. I don't see any faster way

Comment: Don't take colleagues' statements for truths as long as you don't know their rationale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to take the cotangent *of the angle* between two vectors.

You can indeed first compute the angle with

```
Angle= atan(cross / dot)
```

or better

```
Angle= atan2(cross, dot)
```

This angle can also be obtained as the difference of the directions of the two vectors

```
Angle= atan2(by, bx) - atan2(ay, ax)
```

Then take the cotangent

```
1. / tan(Angle)
```

or the tangent of the complementary angle

```
tan(atan2(dot, cross))
```

Anyway, think that this involves the evaluation of two or three transcendental functions, which is costly and less accurate.

From the third equation above, you can derive

```
cotan(Angle)= (1 + by/bx.ay/ax) / (by/bx - ay/ax)
```

This is just a rewrite of your initial formula, but more costly (3 divisions) and that can fail for more angles.

So

```
(ax bx + ay by) / (ax by - ay bx)
```

is definitely the faster and safer approach.

Unless there are special circumstances like low accuracy being enough, other expressions being computed at the same time or conditions on the vectors, I don't see a better way.

Comment: in last equation you have a typo ... `(ax by - ay by)`  if I am not mistaken it should be `(ax by - ay bx)`

Comment: @Spektre: you are right, thanks.